# Undefined class constant 'MESSAGE_ID_PASSWORD_EXPIRED

Tags: magento2

When i try to connect to admin panel, i got this error

```
Undefined class constant 'MESSAGE_ID_PASSWORD_EXPIRED' in /vendor/magento/module-user/Observer/Backend/AuthObserver.php:210
```

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: @GieDe Magento version 2.4.0

Answer (score 1):

The class constant is defined in the User class. Assuming that you've not edited any files under `vendor/`, I would ensure that DI and Autoloading have been updated properly:

```
$ bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

To ensure that your files have not been tampered with, first ensure that the `AuthObserver.php` file has the `use` statement for the User class. This is the expected output:

```
$ grep "User;" vendor/magento/module-user/Observer/Backend/AuthObserver.php
use Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User as ResourceUser;
use Magento\User\Model\User
```

Then ensure that the User class does have the constant set. This is the expected output:

```
$ grep "public const MESSAGE_ID_PASSWORD_EXPIRED" vendor/magento/module-user/Model/User.php
    public const MESSAGE_ID_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 'magento_user_password_expired';
```